# edit gridview at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I need to retrieve a record from a database and show it in a grid view. I then need to edit that particular record. However, when I attempt this, the following error occurs.

**"The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled."**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code I'm trying is below.

**ASP Page:**

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="empid" HeaderText="id" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="age">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("age") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="gender">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="mobile">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mobile") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mobile") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="qual">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qual") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qual") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testdb%>" UpdateCommand="update [empdetails] SET [name]=@name,[age]=@age,[gender]=@gender,[mobile]=@mobile,[qual]=@qual WHERE [empid]=@id">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="age" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="mobile" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="qual" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from empdetails where empid ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 1):

By showing the edit button like you are:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" />
```

it expects that it is being handled in a [RowEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You would need to add this handler to set the index of the row you are editing.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    EnableModelValidation="True"
    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
```

```cs
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about ADO.NET parameter and how to prepare them:

```
var data = new DataTable();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.pr_EC_SportsGroups_Search_Students", conn);
        cmd.Text = "select * from empdetails where empid = @empId";


        var empId = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", empId);

        //create sql adapter by passing command object
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //fill the data table
        adapter.Fill(data);

        //bind data
        GridView1.DataSource = data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

As for the error itself, you just need to add the event to your markup, see [@j.f](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250262/1880431) answer for more info.

Comment: @j.f. I removed that line I have never seen it like this but you're right.

Comment: Good deal. The only reason I knew that is because I _have_ seen it before. :)